# JSON with Setter/Getter

Tags: java, json, selenium-webdriver, getter-setter

In Selenium, I'm using the JSON file to fetch the data and passing them into Getter methods of certain private variables, but it is throwing an error `org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: keys should be a string`

Below are the lines of code :

```
public class ABC {
    private String systemName;
    JSONObject jsonObj = null;

    public ABC() {
         File filePath = new File(filename);
         FileReader reader = null;
         try {
             reader = new FileReader(filename);
             JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
             JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(reader);
             jsonObj = jsonObject;
         } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         } catch (ParseException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
    }

    public String getSystemName() {
        return (String) jsonObj.get("SystemName");
    }
}

public class DEF {
    ABC abc = new ABC();
    String testString = abc.getSystemName();
}
```

Here the value of `testString` is set to `null`.
(All the required packages are imported)

Comment: "What is the JSON you are trying to parse ?" what exactly you want to know about it ?

Comment: What does jsonObj.get return? Its an object. Can u try with `jsonObj.get("SystemName").toString();`

Comment: Or else u can also use `getString(key)` method to get the desired value.